# R shiny: How to view two datatables from left to right, as well as how to highlight values that are different

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a R shiny app and have two data frames, emp.data_A and emp.data_B, which I can access one at a time by picking from the drop-down choices. Apart from that, I'd want to see both data frames in a single view in the left (emp.data_A) and right (emp.data_B) directions.

In emp.data_B, I'd want also highlight to the values that differ from both data frames (Example Column Salary)

My code:

```
library(shiny)

emp.data_A <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:5),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,735.0,844.25))

emp.data_A


emp.data_B <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:5),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25))
emp.data_B


shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      selectInput("dataset5", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "emp.data_A", "emp.data_B")),
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table5")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset5,
             "emp.data_A" = emp.data_A,
             "emp.data_B" = emp.data_B)
    })
    output$table5 <- renderTable({
      datasetInput()
    })
    
  }
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want the Shiny to show? Could you give the expected output?

Comment: to clear even better : I want to have one more choice to show both the data frames in to left and right in a single view.. is that Possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight to the values that differ from both data frames"?

Comment: There is a disparity in numbers in the Salary column of emp.data_A and emp.data_B, which I wish to highlight.

Comment: I have edited the code, please check

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Comment: @Kumar You might want to consider `DT` for highlighting cells/values. To including two tables side-by-side, use `fluidRow` and `column` and include two `tableOutput` in your `ui`. Then, you can include something in your `ui` to indicate you want "both" (not just A or B), and in `server` check for this selection and show the appropriate corresponding data.

Comment: @Ben, As I am new to Shiny, could you assist me with coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working demo using `gt`.

First, to have two columns side-by-side, you can set the column width in `fluidRow`. I added "both" as an option to the `selectInput`, and if chosen, will show both tables. Otherwise, would just show table A or B as selected. There are a number of alternative ways to layout your `ui` with shiny. I would recommend reviewing the [shiny application layout guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) if you haven't already.

Second, to include different highlighting, you can consider using either `DT` or `gt` packages. With `DT` you can use `rowCallback` with javascript and add a function to determine which cells to highlight. With the `gt` example below, you can use `tab_style` to highlight cells in your table.

In this case, using `which` I created a simple matrix indicating the row and column of differences between the two data frames. Then, looping through this matrix, I added `tab_style` repeated for each row/column combination and set to yellow. Note that only when "both" is selected, with the second table show the highlighted differences. However, you can change this to meet your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput("dataset5", 
                  "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet", "both", "emp.data_A", "emp.data_B")),
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, gt_output("table1")),
      column(width = 6, gt_output("table2"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    datasetInput1 <- reactive({
      if (input$dataset5 == "both" || input$dataset5 == "emp.data_A") {
        emp.data_A 
      } else if (input$dataset5 == "emp.data_B") {
        emp.data_B 
      }
    })
    datasetInput2 <- reactive({
      if (input$dataset5 == "both") {
        tbl_diffs <- which(emp.data_A != emp.data_B, arr.ind = TRUE)
        tbl_gt_B <- emp.data_B %>% 
          gt()
        for (i in seq_len(nrow(tbl_diffs))) {
          tbl_gt_B <- tbl_gt_B %>%
            tab_style(
              style = list(
                cell_fill(color = "#FFFF00")
              ),
              locations = cells_body(
                columns = tbl_diffs[[i, "col"]],
                rows = tbl_diffs[[i, "row"]]
              )
            )
        }
        tbl_gt_B
      }
    })
    output$table1 <- render_gt(
      datasetInput1() 
    )
    output$table2 <- render_gt(
      datasetInput2()
    )
  }
)
```